# Setting API Specific API version of a Flow in metadata API

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata

I have a flow that was declaratively defined and I am attempting to add it to source-control. I am seeing other posts about versioning the flows in CI/VC tools but leaving that aside for now.

I am working in VS Code, I have a project with manifest - I added the following to my package.xml:

```
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    ...
    <version>48.0</version>
```

I've retrieved the metadata, and when I attempt to deploy it from VS-Code I get an error:

> Property 'getFirstRecordOnly' not valid in version 46.0 (343:20)

Sure enough, this property is in my metadata definition file and [per. documentation, this property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) was added in API Version 47.0

However, I cannot find an "API Version" Property for the Flow in the metadata?

Comment: what's the `sourceApiVersion` in the sfdx-project.json?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves that was the issue, I updated it to `48.0` and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make sure you `sourceApiVersion` is 47.0 or higher in your sfdx-project.json file.

The documentation about [Salesforce DX Project Configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm) mentions the following:

> The sourceApiVersion determines the fields retrieved for each metadata type during source:push, source:pull, or source:convert. **This field is important if you’re using a metadata type that has changed in a recent release**. You’d want to specify the version of your metadata source.